# How to move datastore entities from development server to production server and vice-versa?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Sometimes I need to have some data taken from production server and copy it to development server for testing purposes. Is there any easy way or a tool for moving datastore entities from one to another?

Probably something like:

```
move_data.py <local-app-id> <remote-app-id> <entity-kind>
```

There is bulkloader.py but it requires writing code.

Comment: For small amounts of entities say < 100,000 entities you can use the remote_api

Answer (score 0):

This document explains the basic idea, but it comes with serious limitations:

[Uploading and Downloading Data in Python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/uploadingdata#Loading_Data_Into_the_Development_Server)

Answer (score 0):

OK, apparently there are some ways to do this.

First, enable remote_api built-in in `app.yaml`:

```
builtins:
- remote_api: on
```

Then download the production server data to a cryptic file:

```
appcfg.py download_data --filename=/tmp/data1 --url='http://yourappid.appspot.com/_ah/remote_api' --kind=EntityKind
```

Then upload the cryptic file data to the development server:

```
appcfg.py upload_data --filename=/tmp/data1 --url='http://localhost:14082/_ah/remote_api' --kind=EntityKind
```

When asked for password for development server, use:

```
Please enter login credentials for localhost:14082
Email: aaa@gmail.com
Password for aaa@gmail.com: a
```